# How do you create a browser in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I have a very simple application that is intended to run a web browser in PyQt window.

The code runs without errors the window opens and then 'blinks' briefly and then is blank.

I am running MacOS(10.13.6)  Python 3.8  and PyQt5 5.14 and PyQtWebEngine 5.14.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://google.com"))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: it works correctly on Linux Mint 19,2 (based on Ubuntu 18.04), Python 3.7.6

Comment: did you run in console/terminal to see error messages?

Comment: A few days ago another user pointed out the same as you: QWebEngineView failed in MacOS, and in the end he realized that it was a bug of Qt 5.14 in MacOS so in the end he used the previous version: PyQt 5.13.2 and PyQtWebEngine 5.13.2. That same user indicated that his code worked correctly on other OS with Qt 5.14.

Comment: @furas, yes, I was using teriminal. No error messages.

Comment: @eyllansesc.  Thank you I will try installing earlier version. I will also search for the other post. Apologies, I am a newb!